# Moving chunks of code in Dreamweaver with RegEx

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I am working on correcting validation issues on several pages at work. Since these pages were last reviewed, the proper way to code a table was to put the `<tfoot>` between the `</thead>` and `<tbody>`. Since then, the powers that be that decide on validation decided that `<tfoot>` is to go after `</tbody>`. Some pages have dozens of tables where these need to be moved.

I am wondering if there is a way to capture everything between `</thead>` and `<tbody>` and move it after `</tbody>`. I have a basic understanding of regular expressions, but I cannot figure out how to get it to find the footer content. And the content is not the same in all the footers.

Examples:

```
<tfoot>
    <tr> 
      <td class="small text-left" colspan="6">Source: Mintel <abbr title="Global New Products Database">GNPD</abbr>, 2015.<br>
        Note: rankings are based on 2014 data and <abbr title="Global New Products Database">GNPD</abbr> search was based solely 
        on products that contained a form of the word "flax."</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
```

And

```
<tfoot>
    <tr> 
      <td class="small text-left" colspan="5">Source: Global Trade Atlas, 
        2015 <br>
         Compound Annual Growth Rate (CAGR) </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
```

Basically, turn something like this:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered text-right table-condensed mrgn-tp-lg">
<caption>Top 5 Pet Food Companies Worldwide in 2014, US$</caption>
  <thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col" class="active text-center">Company</th>
    <th scope="col" class="active text-center">International Sales</th>
    <th scope="col" class="active text-center">Sales in the EU</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td class="small text-left" colspan="3">Source: Euromonitor International, 2015</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><b>1. Mars <abbr title="Incorporated">Inc.</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$17.8 billion</td>
    <td>$5.7 billion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2. Nestlé <abbr lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" title="Société Anonym">SA</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$16.8 billion</td>
    <td>$4.1 billion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>3. Colgate-Palmolive <abbr title="Company">Co</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$3.7 billion</td>
    <td>$0.7 billion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>4. Big Heart Pet Brand</b></td>
    <td>$2.9 billion</td>
    <td>Not available (N/A)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>5. Blue Buffalo <abbr title="Company">Co</abbr> <abbr title="Limited">Ltd</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$1.4 billion</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

into this:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered text-right table-condensed mrgn-tp-lg">
<caption>Top 5 Pet Food Companies Worldwide in 2014, US$</caption>
  <thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col" class="active text-center">Company</th>
    <th scope="col" class="active text-center">International Sales</th>
    <th scope="col" class="active text-center">Sales in the EU</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><b>1. Mars <abbr title="Incorporated">Inc.</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$17.8 billion</td>
    <td>$5.7 billion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2. Nestlé <abbr lang="fr" xml:lang="fr" title="Société Anonym">SA</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$16.8 billion</td>
    <td>$4.1 billion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>3. Colgate-Palmolive <abbr title="Company">Co</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$3.7 billion</td>
    <td>$0.7 billion</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>4. Big Heart Pet Brand</b></td>
    <td>$2.9 billion</td>
    <td>Not available (N/A)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>5. Blue Buffalo <abbr title="Company">Co</abbr> <abbr title="Limited">Ltd</abbr></b></td>
    <td>$1.4 billion</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<td class="small text-left" colspan="3">Source: Euromonitor International, 2015</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: It is only possible with assumptions.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It is not possible to safely regex-replace HTML content. Only if you know the values you want to match only occur in unambiguous contexts can you safely use a regex.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to find everything between </thead> and <tbody>, capture it, and move to after </tbody>. I figure that would require capturing everthing between <tbody> and </tbody> and putting it back as well.

Is there a way to do it with an outside program, like an AutoHotKey script that would go into the html file on my desktop and make the changes?

Comment: I think it is relatively easy *with assumptions*. What have you tried? BTW you have not provided a sample text with exact expected output.

Comment: I added an example of a table to change in my opening post. But I still don't know what you mean when you say with assumptions.

Comment: Ok, assumption  is that `<tbody>`, `</tbody>`, `</thead>` do not appear inside comments. Then, you may use [`(?is)(</thead>\s*)([^<]*(?:<(?!tbody>)[^<]*)*\S)\s*(<tbody>([^<]*(?:<(?!/tbody>)[^<]*)*)</tbody>)`](https://regex101.com/r/CKP4Yq/2) to replace wtih `$1$3\n$2`.

Comment: Note the above can be written as [`(?is)(</thead>\s*)(.*?)\s*(<tbody>.*?</tbody>)`](https://regex101.com/r/CKP4Yq/3), but this one is about 4 times as slow than the above.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try on Monday when I'm at work, and I'll report back  :)

Comment: Dreamweaver gives me a Regular Expression Syntax Error:

Invalid quantifier
?is)(</thead>\s*)([^<]*(?:<(?!tbody>)[^<]*)*\S)\s*(<tbody>([^<]*(?:<(?!/tbody>)[^<]*)*)</tbody>)

Please note that I copied the entire string into the Find box, including the first ( which is omitted in the error. The same thing happens with the shorter version.

Comment: You pasted a wrong pattern in the comment above. Did you copy the pattern from the https://regex101.com/r/CKP4Yq/3 fiddle? Please do not copy long patterns from SO comments, SO adds rubbish chars into the comments for better visual display.

Comment: This time I copied from https://regex101.com/r/CKP4Yq/3 from the regular expression box at the top of the page and Dreamweaver gave me the same error.

Comment: Ok, it does not make sense to me, but it seems inline modifiers are not parsed. Use `(</thead>\s*)([\s\S]*?)\s*(<tbody>[\s\S]*?</tbody>)`

Comment: That worked. You're a genius. Thank you a million times over :). How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(</thead>\s*)([\s\S]*?)\s*(<tbody>[\s\S]*?</tbody>)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CKP4Yq/5). Replace with `$1$3\n$2`.

**Details**

- `(</thead>\s*)` - Group 1: a `</thead>` substring and 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(<tbody>[\s\S]*?</tbody>)` - Group 3:

  - `<tbody>` - a `<tbody>` substring
  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost occurrence of...
  - `</tbody>` - a `</tbody>` substring.

The `$1$3\n$2` replaces the matches with Group 1 value, then Group 3 value, then inserts a newline, and then Group 2 value.